# ROLLBACK make data in INSERTED table is removed in AFTER INSERT TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions, insert, rollback

I give an example to show my problem. I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    id INT
)
```

I then created an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to not allow insert `id = 1` into table `a`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_a]
ON [dbo].[a] AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = id FROM inserted

    IF @id = 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('1', 12, 1)
        ROLLBACK;
    END

    SELECT * FROM inserted
END
```

Then I insert `id = 1` into table `a`:

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1)
```

I get nothing from `INSERTED` table.

I realize that when I ROLLBACK then + the data in table `a` was rolled back (I know) and data in `INSERTED` table is also removed. Why is that?

If I change the `AFTER INSERT` trigger to an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_a]
ON [dbo].[a] INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = id FROM inserted

    IF @id = 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('1', 12, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END

    SELECT * FROM inserted
END

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1)
```

Then I get the result:

```
id
1
```

That means data in `INSERTED` table is not removed though have been ROLLBACK.

Help me explain deeply what happens inside trigger?

Comment: Welcome!, You said `data in INSERTED table is also removed.Why is that?` are you sure ? I executed your code and everything seems fine!, also change  RAISERROR command to be `RAISERROR(' I am In the Begin and End block after inserting into inserted table',12,1)` just for more Clarification, also please notify 
[the data is existing into inserted table only while executing DML commands then the data has gone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables).

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows. If someone inserts multiple rows where *some* of them have `id` 1 then a) What should the trigger do and b) Your current trigger only picks up one of the `id`s so may not react. Why do you not just have a `check` constraint instead?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I just give an simple example to clarify my problem.My problem just is why data in INSERTED table is removed when ROLLBACK

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour as far as I know. It's just that AFTER may be a bit misleading depending on how you look at it.

"The trigger and the statement that fires it are treated as a single transaction, which can be rolled back from within the trigger. If a severe error is detected, the entire transaction automatically rolls back.".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx